# вствка вектора векторов в вектор векторов

Tags: c++, vector

Как вставить вектор векторов в вектор векторов после `k`-того элемента.То есть если у нас есть вектор векторов 10 на 10, то нужно будет вставить второй вектор векторов 5 на 10 чтобы вышло 15 на 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно использовать метод `insert` класса `std::vector`, принимающий диапазон значений, заданных с помощью входных итераторов.

Ниже, в демонстрационной программе показано, как это можно сделать.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> v1(10, std::vector<int>( 10, 0 ));
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> v2(5, std::vector<int>( 10, 1 ));
    size_t k = 5;

    for ( const auto &row : v1 )
    {
        for ( int x : row ) std::cout << x << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    v1.insert( std::next( v1.begin(), k ), v2.begin(), v2.end() );

    for ( const auto &row : v1 )
    {
        for ( int x : row ) std::cout << x << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

В общем случае вам надо проверять, что значение переменной `k` не превышает значения, возвращаемого функцией-членом класса `std::vector` `size`. В противном случае в качестве позиции вставки вместо выражения `std::next( v1.begin(), k )` вам следует использовать выражение `v1.end()`.